# SQL Server Set ANSI_PADDING on new column

Tags: sql-server

I am altering an existing table by adding a new column and foreign key constraint. I would like this new column to have "TrimTrailingBlanks" enabled like rest of the columns in the table. The Column is nullable. Below is script I used to alter and create the new column.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

-- Alter Table to add column
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

ALTER TABLE <tablename>
ADD <column name> VARCHAR(5) null
GO

-- Add foreign key constrain
ALTER TABLE <tablename>
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint name>
FOREIGN KEY <column name>
REFERENCES <Ref Table(ref column)>;
GO

COMMIT
GO
```

However when I check the table properties after, the new column does NOT have trim enabled (tried without the foreign key constraint as well, but it doesn't matter) Column and foreign key constraints are created fine. Help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ANSI_PADDING ON` doesn't trim trailing blank spaces.
`ANSI_PADDING_OFF` does.

[SET ANSI_PADDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Changed SET ANSI_PADDING ON; to SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;